# Pandas Dataframe column Validation

Tags: python, pandas

i have a pandas dataframe with 30 columnns and 4000 rows.

for about 5 columns i need to validate that it meets data validation
is there a way to say something like "`if df.Gender contains any value thats not 'M' or 'F' then print error`"

or `if df.MaritalStatus contains a value thats not M, S, D then print error.`

[sample of df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJpnJ.png)

anyone have any best way of applying the conditions?

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/ABV1234/Desktop/DailyReport.csv")
```

##if df.Gender contains value that is not in ['m', 'f'] print Error

Comment: Plz add your sample code.. so everyone can understand your perspective.

Comment: You will need to include a [`reproducible example`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) along with expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if any of `['M', 'F']` are in the values of `df.Gender`:

```
if not any(x in df.Gender.values for x in ['M','F'])
    print("Error")
```

Comment: This does almost what i need.
If all df.gender is M this still prints an error
If all gender is M that should be fine because M and F are acceptable values

Comment: Oh I see. So either 'M' or 'F'. I will update my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Checking the 1st condition

`if df.Gender contains any value thats not 'M' or 'F' then print error`

```
gender_series = df.Gender.values

for x in gender_series:
    if x not in ('M', 'F'):
        print("error")
```

Checking the second Condition:

`if df.MaritalStatus contains a value thats not M, S, D then print error.`

```
maritalstatus_series = df.MaritalStatus.values

for x in maritalstatus_series:
    if x not in ('M', 'S', 'D'):
        print("error")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A possible improvement on the above answers would be to collect and report all the failure cases after evaluating the entire column.

This will return a filtered dataframe of all cases where Gender column is not equal to 'M' or 'F'.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"MaritalStatus":["M","S","F"],"Gender":["M","S","F"]})
df.loc[~df.loc[:,"Gender"].isin(['M','F']),:] 
>>>  MaritalStatus Gender
    1             S      S
```

The same can be done for marital status:

```py
df.loc[~df.loc[:,"MaritalStatus"].isin(['M','S','D']),:]
>>>  MaritalStatus Gender
    2             F      F
```

If you're spot-checking the data for unexpected values, you can then get the values that fail these conditions:

```py
expected_values = {"MaritalStatus":['M','S','D'],"Gender":['M','F']}
for feature in expected_values:
    print(f"The following unexpected values were found in {feature} column:",
    set(df.loc[~df.loc[:,feature].isin(expected_values[feature]),:][feature]))
>>> The following unexpected values were found in MaritalStatus column: {'F'}
>>> The following unexpected values were found in Gender column: {'S'}
```

Alternatively, you can use the [pandera](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library, which allows you to establish expectations of your dataset and validate it against those expectations. Doing lazy evaluation allows you to see all the fail cases at once instead of getting a failure at each individual case.

```py
import pandera as pa

schema = pa.DataFrameSchema(
    {
"MaritalStatus":pa.Column(pa.String, checks=pa.Check.isin(["M","S","D"])),
"Gender":pa.Column(pa.String, checks=pa.Check.isin(["M","F"]))
    },strict=False
)
schema.validate(df,lazy=True)

>>> 
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Daten\venv\lib\site-packages\pandera\schemas.py", line 592, in validate
    error_handler.collected_errors, check_obj
pandera.errors.SchemaErrors: A total of 2 schema errors were found.

Error Counts
------------
- schema_component_check: 2

Schema Error Summary
--------------------
                                                   failure_cases  n_failure_cases
schema_context column        check
Column         Gender        isin({'F', 'M'})                [S]                1
               MaritalStatus isin({'M', 'D', 'S'})           [F]                1
```